# how to solve partial sum of $jH_j$ where $H_j$ is the harmonic series

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ $$\sum\limits_{j=1}^n jH_j = \left[ \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]H_{n+1} -\left[ \dfrac{n(n+1)}{4}\right]\;.$$

Comment: Have you tried to prove it by induction on $n$? That proof is really quite straightforward. Non-inductive proofs are also possible.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent to prove that 
$$\left[ \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]H_{n+1} - \sum\limits_{j=1}^n jH_j =  \left[ \dfrac{n(n+1)}{4}\right]\;.$$
left hand side can be rewritten
$$\sum\limits_{j=1}^n jH_{n+1} - \sum\limits_{j=1}^n jH_j =  \sum\limits_{j=1}^n j(H_{n+1}-H_j) :=A_n$$
We look at how this thing grows by substracting successive terms. $A_{n+1}-A_n = (n+1)(H_{n+2}-H_{n+1}) + \sum\limits_{j=1}^n j(H_{n+2}-H_{n+1}) = (n+1)\frac{1} {n+2} + \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \frac{1}{n+2} = \frac{2(n+1) + n(n+1)}{2(n+2)} = \frac{n+1}{2}$

Now we build $A_n$ back by telescoping
$$A_n = A_1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (A_{k+1} - A_k) = 1/2 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{k+1}{2} = 1/2( \sum_{k=1}^{n} k) = \frac{n(n+1)}{4}$$

Comment: Actually you can use Abel's lemma which does the same thing : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts

Answer (score 0):

HINT: For a proof by induction your induction hypothesis will be that

$$\sum_{j=1}^njH_j=\frac{n(n+1)}2H_{n+1}-\frac{n(n+1)}4\;,$$

and you’ll want to prove that

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}jH_j=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}2H_{n+2}-\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}4\;.\tag{1}$$

The first step should be obvious:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}jH_j=\sum_{j=1}^njH_j+(n+1)H_{n+1}=\frac{n(n+1)}2H_{n+1}-\frac{n(n+1)}4+(n+1)H_{n+1}\;.\tag{2}$$

Now you just need to do some algebra to show that the righthand side of $(2)$ is equal to the righthand side of $(1)$; you will find it useful to remember that $H_{n+2}=H_{n+1}+\frac1{n+2}$.

It is also possible to prove the result simply by manipulating summations and using the well-known formula for the sum of an arithmetic progression:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^njH_j&=\sum_{j=1}^nj\sum_{k=1}^j\frac1k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=k}^n\frac{j}k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\sum_{j=k}^nj\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\left(\frac{(n+k)(n-k+1)}2\right)\\
&=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n^2-k^2+n+k}k\\
&=\frac12\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n^2+n}k-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2-k}k\right)\\
&=\frac12(n^2+n)H_n-\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n(k-1)\;,
\end{align*}$$

and I’ll leave the last few steps to you.

Comment: @Zeeshan: You’re very welcome.